# Blocking a website based on title with Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was experimenting with Chrome extensions trying to make one that can block and redirect a website based on its title. In this example case, when any webpage title has the value "Microsoft - Official Home Page" I want it to redirect to https://example.com/. The sample code I put below almost works, the problem is that I have to refresh the page the first time I go to it, or else it doesn't redirect me to example.com. Why doesn't it redirect me the first time it sees a page with the specified title without me having to refresh it, and what should I do about it?

background.js:

```js
// Listens for a change to occur.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {

  // Gets the URL and title of the webpage in the selected tab.
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab) {
    var currentUrl = tab.url;
    var currentTitle = tab.title;

    // Tests if the page title is equal to the given string.
    if(currentTitle == "Microsoft - Official Home Page") {

      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function() {
          return {redirectUrl: "https://example.com/"};
        },
        {urls: [currentUrl]}, // Blocks the URL of the current tab.
        ["blocking"]
      );

    }
  }
}
```

manifest.json:

```js
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "An extension to block sites by title.",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "tabCapture",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

- Your code is registering a new webRequest listener in addition to all the previous ones each time the title condition was true.
- The webRequest listener works on a subsequent navigation, it doesn't actively run by itself.
- chrome.tabs.getSelected is deprecated and not needed here altogether.

Solution:

When a tab's title becomes known, [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener is invoked with the `change` parameter containing the new title. If the title is already known - e.g. when the tab is reloaded - there's no change notification for the title, but only for the status (e.g. loading/complete) so we use `tab.title` instead.

Here's the correct background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, change, tab) => {
  const title = 'title' in change ? change.title : tab.title;
  if (title === 'Microsoft - Official Home Page') {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: 'https://example.com/'});
  }
});
```

The only manifest.json permissions needed for the above to work:

```js
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
```